Given a TM $M$ Denote $L(M), L_{rej}(M), L_{non-halt} (M)$, Is $L(M)\in R$ implies $L_{rej}(M)\in R$?
Question:
Given the following definitions for a Turing machine $M$:
$$
L_{rej}(M) = \{w \in \Sigma^* : q_0w \vdash_M^* uq_{rej}v\}
$$
Basically, represents the language of words that $M$ rejects (i.e., $M$ halts and rejects these words), and
$$
L_{non-halt}(M) = \{w \in \Sigma^* : M \text{ does not halt on } w\}
$$
where $L_{non-halt}(M)$ represents the set of words on which $M$ does not halt.
The question is:

If it is known that $L(M) \in R$, does it follow that $L_{rej}(M) \in R$ ? Prove or disprove this claim.

Note:
I lean towards the possibility that the claim is false, but I am having difficulty constructing a reduction or proof for this claim.

Please define $R$. Why introduce $L_\text{non-halt}$ if it doesn't appear in your question?

R is a known set in this topic, the set of all languages for which exists a decidable TM. Non-halt set is introduced in the original question, letting you know that $\bar{L(M)} \ne L_{rej}(M)$ and there's another portion. A hint I would say.

Consider the machine $M$ that takes another TM as input, runs it, and then inconditionally rejects. Then $L(M)$ is empty and $L_\text{rej}(M)$ is undecidable. Does this answer your question?

@NaïmFavier, This seems like an answer, please consider posting it formally.

Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so all relevant context and background is contained in the question, and it reads well for someone who encounters this for the first time.  Once you've addressed a comment, flag it as 'no longer needed'.
